# Add Acrylic effect on Button Flyout

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

In Xaml, I have simple Flyout windows like the ones described below:

```
<Button Content="Clickable">
  <Button.Flyout>
    <Flyout>
      <TextBlock Text="My Flyout have several text elements"/>
    </Flyout>
  </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

How can I apply the Windows 10 acrylic effect on the Flyout panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Button Content="Clickable" Height="55" Width="255" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealStyle}">
    <Button.Flyout>
        <Flyout>
            <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlAcrylicElementMediumHighBrush}" />
                </Style>
            </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
            <TextBlock Text="My Flyout have several text elements"/>
        </Flyout>
    </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

[image: Screenshot]

You Should Check this [app](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9MSVH128X2ZT) to view more about controls and for more customize acrylic brush